# AdMob [GADObjectPrivate changeState:] error on iOS - NOT able to resolve through -ObjC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

After reading many SO posts about the same error, I cant seem to resolve the problem with AdMob.

Im trying to implement it into my existing app and I copied the SDK and followed the tutorial.

All compiles fine but the app crashes with:

```
[GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5cc610'
```

They say I need to add -ObjC or -all_load to Other Linker Flags.

When I do that, I get many, many duplicate symbol errors.

Since Im upgrading a project from a different developer, I dont know 
the exact structure of the code.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Fix the duplicate symbol warnings.  -all_load and -ObjC work fine, and introduce new symbols into your binary which you just refused to resolve by hand.

Comment: thx, how do I fix the duplicate warnings? I did not write most of the code so that makes it more difficult

Comment: Search for the symbols it mentions (you should see something like "someFunction/someOtherClass in OBJ_C_CLASS_$_SomeClass"), then remove one of them, or forward-declare it.  Keep building every so often. Not you do it right, your errors will decrease with each build.

Comment: so I have about 100 duplicates like: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPElement in:
    /Users/mirzahat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chattar-ajtakwrcojkkiehegfaxjkhesaej/Build/Intermediates/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/Objects-normal/i386/XMPPElement.o ------ so the goal is to find it on disk (the .o file) and delete it?

Comment: No, the goal is to find where it is referenced multiple times (perhaps the XMPP framework got duplicated and is imported twice?), and get down to using only one library/class/function instead of many conflicting ones.  The disk locations just show you where the linker had to stop.

Comment: the XMPP framework is there because its a facebook chat app and I see this https://www.dropbox.com/s/16hwnxdc45u1vsg/import.png could this the reason it got imported twice?

Comment: The dropbox image file has been deleted.

Comment: Only use `-ObjC`, don't use `-all_load`.

Answer (score 0):

When you using the Abmob API, they add 2 API for you. 1 for Debug and 1 for real.
2 API have same functions and many things. 
(Try to see what happen in your debug screen, they will give you the location of duplicated folder - It in Google Library 3.0/GoogleAnalysis/Library/lib - ...debug.lib)

The simple solution is remove the Debug API and you will be fine.

**Addition:** Adding ObjC is right for your program, it is other problem.